# How to connect the Bluetooth device in Android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth device.

I can scan the bluetooth device and list the paired by ListView.

I want to connect to the bluetooth device when I click the device on ListView.

This java code is the action when I click the device Item on ListView.

```
pair_devices_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

                AlertDialog.Builder deviceInfo = new AlertDialog.Builder(DeviceList.this);
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();//stop scan             

                String info = ((TextView) arg1).getText().toString();
                String address = info.substring(info.length()-18);

                BluetoothDevice connect_device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);                

                try {
                    BluetoothSocket socket = connect_device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(my_UUID);
                    socket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

When I execute the APP, it always crase when I type the code of following:

```
BluetoothDevice connect_device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
```

But when I change the string "`address`" to the address `device.getAddress`, It work normal.

I show the string `address`. 
It content is the MAC address of bluetoothdevice, but it type is the string.

And the type of `getRemoteDevice` here I choose the string.

So I don't Why the APP always crash when I use the string `address`???

Answer (score 0):

MAC address consists of 17 characters, and you take 18.

```
String address = info.substring(info.length()-17);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that piece of code with substring info etc. is necessary. Try simply initialise your string like this:

```
String address = device.getAddress;
```